Project a boolean mask from max-pooling regions back onto the input tensor
I’m working on implementing a custom max-pooling layer in TensorFlow and need help projecting a boolean mask onto the input tensor to indicate the positions that contributed to the max values in each pooling window.
I want to avoid using loops and I am looking for an efficient vectorized solution that fully leverages the parallel computing capabilities of the GPU.
Input
Here’s a simplified version of my current setup:

Input Tensor Shape: (batch_size, input_height, input_width, n_channels)
Pooling Window Size: (pool_height, pool_width)
Strides: (stride_height, stride_width)

I use tf.image.extract_patches to get all pooling regions from the input in a single step, then reshape it to isolate each pooling window. I then compute the max over each window to get the output tensor and create a boolean mask indicating the positions of the maximum values.
Here is my code:
import tensorflow as tf

# Input dimensions
batch_size = 3
input_height = 4
input_width = 4
n_channels = 3
pool_height = 2
pool_width = 2
stride_height = 2
stride_width = 2

# Input tensor
x = tf.random.normal((batch_size, input_height, input_width, n_channels)) # Shape: (batch_size, input_height, input_width, n_channels)

print("Input:")
print(x[0, :, :, 0])

# Extract patches for all pooling regions in one step
patches = tf.image.extract_patches(
    images = x,
    sizes = [1, pool_height, pool_width, 1],
    strides = [1, stride_height, stride_width, 1],
    rates = [1, 1, 1, 1],
    padding = "VALID"
)  # Shape: (batch_size, output_height, output_width, pool_height * pool_width * n_channels)

# Reshape patches to isolate each channel and pooling window
_, output_height, output_width, _ = patches.shape
patches = tf.reshape(patches, [batch_size, output_height, output_width, pool_height, pool_width, n_channels])  # Shape: (batch_size, output_height, output_width, pool_height, pool_width, n_channels)

# Compute max over the pooling window
output = tf.reduce_max(patches, axis=(3, 4))  # Shape: (batch_size, output_height, output_width, n_channels)

print("\nOutput:")
print(output[0, :, :, 0])

# Create a mask for the positions of the maxima
max_values = tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(output, axis=3), axis=4)  # Shape: (batch_size, output_height, output_width, 1, 1, n_channels)
mask = tf.equal(patches, max_values)  # Shape: (batch_size, output_height, output_width, pool_height, pool_width, n_channels)

print("\nMask:")
print(mask[0, :, : ,:, :, 0])

# The tensor I want to obtain
cache = tf.reshape(mask, tf.shape(x)) # Shape: (batch_size, input_height, input_width, n_channels)

print("\nCache:")
print(cache[0, :, :, 0])

Output
The output I obtain is this (For simplicity I displayed only the first channel of the first element of the batch):
Input:
tf.Tensor(
[[ 1.8739315  -1.1739935   0.21598558 -1.0357039 ]
 [ 0.5625862   1.6689821   0.6279541  -0.6442553 ]
 [-1.4488437   0.4760101  -0.34631395  0.25045732]
 [ 0.8405037  -1.8099107   1.0800457   0.06632996]], shape=(4, 4), dtype=float32)

Output:
tf.Tensor(
[[1.8739315 0.6279541]
 [0.8405037 1.0800457]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32)

Mask:
tf.Tensor(
[[[[ True False]
   [False False]]

  [[False False]
   [ True False]]]


 [[[False False]
   [ True False]]

  [[False False]
   [ True False]]]], shape=(2, 2, 2, 2), dtype=bool)

Cache:
tf.Tensor(
[[ True False False False]
 [False False  True False]
 [False False  True False]
 [False False  True False]], shape=(4, 4), dtype=bool)

As you can see, even if the mask seems correct, the cache tensor has some wrong values.
